# Regex range between 0 and 75 including two decimal digits

Tags: regex, validation

I'm beginner with regex, so when it comes to it, I'm trying to learn it by looking for similar problems here on stack, but after a lot of trying I'm getting stuck and I can't find where is the problem in my own regex.

I'm looking for someone to help me with my already created regex (provided below) or to give me a better regex idea/solution.

I need a regex that include numbers in range between 0 and 75 with maximum 4 digits, including 2 decimal digits. For example **75.00** or **15.50**, but also full number without decimal digits should be valid number such as: **75, 15** (not included **00**).

Here is couple of numbers down below that should be valid and not valid:

**VALID NUMBERS:**

```
0
0.1
0.10
5.15
5.52
15.50
74.99
75.00
75
```

**NOT VALID NUMBERS:**

```
00
-10
-0
-0.50
00.50
05.15
75.01
76.00
76
76.19
```

And here is my already created regex that should be obviously fixed:

```
^(75(?:\.00?)?|[1-7]?[0-5](?:\.\d\d?)?|\d(?:\.\d?\d)?)$
```

Also here is [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hW9kP5/4).

p.s. I was looking for similar answer on [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25252506/float-regex-format-for-a-2-decimal-place-number-between-0-and-100).

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/ceghnH/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fix your pattern the following way:

```
^(?:75(?:\.00?)?|7[0-4](?:\.\d\d?)?|[1-6]?\d(?:\.\d\d?)?)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ceghnH/2)

**Details**:

- `^(?:` - start of string and the start of a non-capturing group (so as the anchors could be applied to all the alternatives in the alternation group)
- `75(?:\.00?)?` - `75` followed with an optional sequence of `.`, `0` and an optional `0`
- `|` - or
- `7[0-4](?:\.\d\d?)?` - `7` followed with a digit from `0` to `4` and then followed with an optional sequence of `.`, a digit and then an optional digit
- `|` - or
- `[1-6]?\d(?:\.\d\d?)?` - an optional digit from `1` to `6`, followed with any 1 digit and then an optional sequence of `.`, a digit and then an optional digit
- `)$` - the end of the first group and end of string

Comment: Thanks a lot for the regex and explanation. Now everything makes sense what I missed. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I liked a lot playing with this RegEx tool from your demo.  I think you need to add more classes to your RegEx:

^(([1-6]?[0-9])$|^(7[0-5])$|^(([1-6]?[0-9])).[0-9][0-9]?)$|^((7[0-4]).[0-9][0-9]?)$|^(75.00?)$

Regards,

Comment: Yes, it's a nice tool. Thanks for your answer.